# Sort data by cell background color using VBA in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, sorting, worksheet-function, vba

Thanks in advance.

Can someone help me in sorting the data using cell background color in **Excel 2003.**

I've 400 rows out of which 30 rows has Cell range A1 filled with background color yellow. I need to sort the data based on color in VBA to reduce the number of iterations I do on data ( If i can sort the data, the sorted data will be on top and I can only parse 30 rows instead of looping all 400 rows).

Comment: Developer Tab -> Record Macro -> Do the filter manually -> Stop Recording -> Alt + F11 to view the code

Comment: I cannot see an advanced option for sort in Excel 2003. I need that to sort by format. How can i enable it ? Until the advanced sort is enabled recording a macro is of no use..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Excel 2007, you may perform this task in following steps: first, select the Worksheet Range, then click on `Sort->Advanced`, then in Dialog Box select "`Sort On`" option "**Cell Color**", and customize it pertinent to your task. You can use a Macro Recorder to generate the basic VBA code (include it in your post if you want us to optimize it).

Pertinent to Excel 2003, the possible solution will be using a helper function placed in the code Module:

```
' in Excel 2003 it could be Public by default if placed in code Module
Public Function BackgroundColorIndex(myRange As Range)
    BackgroundColorIndex = myRange.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

then adding this function to some auxiliary Column and sorting on the values in that Column. This solution will also work in the later Excel versions (2007+).

Hope this will help.

Comment: I cannot see an advanced option for sort in Excel 2003. How can i enable it ?

Comment: I have extended the answer providing the universal solution. Best regards,